# Проблема с удовлетворением интерфейсу в Go

Tags: golang, интерфейс

Нижеприведенный код не удовлетворяет созданному для него интерфейсу (думаю, всем понятно для чего интерфейс - DIP, модули верхнего уровня не должны зависеть от деталей и т.д.).

Ошибка при компиляции.

```
.\http_client_interface.go:118:13: cannot use NewClient() (type *Client) as type HTTPClient in assignment:
        *Client does not implement HTTPClient (wrong type for Classic method)
                have Classic() *Classic
                want Classic() Requester
```

В упор не понимаю почему он не удовлетворяет этому интерфейсу.

Упрощенный код (именно поэтому в одном пакете - в реальности, конечно, нет), который можно запустить.

```go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "time"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"

)


func NewClient(timeouts ...time.Duration) *Client {
    timeout := 120 * time.Second
    if len(timeouts) > 0 {
        timeout = timeouts[0]
    }

    return &Client{
        classic: NewClassic(timeout),
        Timeout: timeout,
    }
}

func NewClassic(timeouts ...time.Duration) *Classic {
    timeout := 120 * time.Second
    if len(timeouts) > 0 {
        timeout = timeouts[0]
    }

    return &Classic{
        Client: &http.Client{Timeout: timeout},
    }
}


type Client struct {
    classic *Classic
    Timeout time.Duration
}


func (client *Client) SetTimeout(timeout time.Duration) {
    client.Timeout = timeout
}


type Classic struct {
    *http.Client
}

func (client *Client) Classic() *Classic {
    return client.classic
}


func (client *Classic) SetTimeout(timeout time.Duration) {
    client.Client.Timeout = timeout
}

func (client *Classic) Get(
    urlPath string, queryValues url.Values, headerValues http.Header,
    cookies ...*http.Cookie) *Response {
    // тут много кода.... который не нужен для демонстрации
    return &Response{}
      
}


type Response struct {
    status int
    err    error
    body   []byte
}

func (r *Response) Body() []byte {

    if r.body == nil {
        return []byte{}
    }

    return r.body
}

func (r *Response) Reader() io.ReadCloser {
    return io.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(r.body))
}

func (r *Response) Error() error {
    return r.err
}

func (r *Response) Status() int {
    return r.status
}

//-----------------------------------------------
// интерфейс
//-----------------------------------------------
type HTTPClient interface {
    SetTimeout(time.Duration)
    Classic() Requester
}
 
type Responser interface {
    Body() []byte
    Reader() io.ReadCloser
    Error() error
    Status() int
}


type Requester interface {
    SetTimeout(time.Duration)
    
    Get(urlPath string,
        query url.Values,
        headers http.Header,
        cookies ...*http.Cookie) Responser
}        



func main(){
     var client HTTPClient
     client =  NewClient()
     
     fmt.Printf("%v\n", client.Classic())
    
}
```

Comment: Чтобы удовлетворять интерфейсу, надо в методе объявлять в точности тот тип, что заявлен в интерфейсе (а вот возвращать уже можно имплементацию)

Comment: В сообщение об ошибке сказано: `want Classic() Requester`. Ваша функция `func (client *Client) Classic() ` должна возвращать не `*Classic`, а `Requester`

Comment: Не понимаю как тогда должен выглядеть код. Не забывайте - это два разных модуля. В одном интерфейс и использование. В другом - (модуле нижнего уровня) - реализация.  Мне, что импортировать интерфейс в реализацию? Requester  находится в одном модуле, а клиент - в другом.

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте сигнатуры двум методам:

- `func (client *Classic) Get(...)` пусть возвращает не конкретный метод `Response`, а интерфейс `Responser`
- `func (client *Client) Classic()` пусть возвращает интерфейс `Requester`

После такой замены приведённая вами тестовая программа компилируется в go 1.16

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "time"
)

func NewClient(timeouts ...time.Duration) *Client {
    timeout := 120 * time.Second
    if len(timeouts) > 0 {
        timeout = timeouts[0]
    }

    return &Client{
        classic: NewClassic(timeout),
        Timeout: timeout,
    }
}

func NewClassic(timeouts ...time.Duration) *Classic {
    timeout := 120 * time.Second
    if len(timeouts) > 0 {
        timeout = timeouts[0]
    }

    return &Classic{
        Client: &http.Client{Timeout: timeout},
    }
}

type Client struct {
    classic *Classic
    Timeout time.Duration
}

func (client *Client) SetTimeout(timeout time.Duration) {
    client.Timeout = timeout
}

type Classic struct {
    *http.Client
}

func (client *Client) Classic() Requester {
    return client.classic
}

func (client *Classic) SetTimeout(timeout time.Duration) {
    client.Client.Timeout = timeout
}

func (client *Classic) Get(
    urlPath string, queryValues url.Values, headerValues http.Header,
    cookies ...*http.Cookie) Responser {
    // тут много кода.... который не нужен для демонстрации
    return &Response{}

}

type Response struct {
    status int
    err    error
    body   []byte
}

func (r *Response) Body() []byte {

    if r.body == nil {
        return []byte{}
    }

    return r.body
}

func (r *Response) Reader() io.ReadCloser {
    return io.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(r.body))
}

func (r *Response) Error() error {
    return r.err
}

func (r *Response) Status() int {
    return r.status
}

//-----------------------------------------------
// интерфейс
//-----------------------------------------------
type HTTPClient interface {
    SetTimeout(time.Duration)
    Classic() Requester
}

type Responser interface {
    Body() []byte
    Reader() io.ReadCloser
    Error() error
    Status() int
}

type Requester interface {
    SetTimeout(time.Duration)

    Get(urlPath string,
        query url.Values,
        headers http.Header,
        cookies ...*http.Cookie) Responser
}

func main() {
    var client HTTPClient
    client = NewClient()

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", client.Classic())

}
```

Comment: Ну я же объяснил, что это упрощенный код. В реальности  код разнесен по двум модулям. Создание самого клиента у меня происходит в main.go. Реализация в client.go. Интерфейсы  и использование - в api.go. И вот как разнести код так, чтобы выполнялась чистая архитектура с границами в виде интерфейсов?

Comment: @GarryGaller во-первых, модули могут состоять из нескольких файлов. То есть ничто не мешает поместить `api.go` и `client.go` в один пакет. Во-вторых, даже если пакеты разные, то вы можете в пакете `client` импортировать пакет `api`. Главное, чтобы не было цикла по импортам

Comment: OK. Я импортировал интерфейс  пакета (постоянно путаю модули и пакеты - в Python все наоборот) api в  пакет client. Мне казалось это не очень хорошим решением. Но, я так понимаю, client как деталь реализации имеет право зависеть от пакета более высокого уровня...